# Remove empty p tags and convert other p tags to \n

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm using cheerio and i have some html like this:

```
<p></p>
<p>test</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>test</p>
```

i'm wondering how i can format this html to something like this using javascript and cheerio.

```
test\ntest\ntest
```

so that if its an empty p tag it should be remove otherwise change it to an \n

Comment: Is this HTML in the DOM on the clientside or in a string on the server? The `node.js` tag is throwing me off here.

Comment: @MaartenBicknese Look up Cheerio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the paragraphs
2. Filter out the empty ones
3. Map the text
4. Turn it into an array
5. Join the array to map the string

.

```
var txt = $('p')   //1
            .filter(function(i, el) {  //2
                return $(this).text().replace(/\s+|&nbsp;/g,"").length;
            }).map( function () { //3
                return $(this).text();
            })
            .get()  //4
            .join("\n");  //5
```

Comment: change `this.textContent` to `$(this).text()` brain is working in jQuery w/ dom

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
jQuery('p').each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
   $this.remove();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your html in `html`, something like this should work:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
var result = '';
$('body').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('p').contents().length) {
     result += $(this).text() + '\n';
  }
});
```